# gcc -Wformat-truncation warning being raised

Tags: c, gcc

gcc 7.1 has introduced a new warning that tells you if you use functions such as `snprintf` and your arguments would result in output truncation.

The [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) implies that it is only raised if you don't check and act upon the return value:

> Level 1 of -Wformat-truncation enabled by -Wformat employs a
>   conservative approach that warns only about calls to bounded functions
>   ***whose return value is unused*** and that will most likely result in
>   output truncation.

Here's a sample compilation unit, compiled with version 7.3.0 that illustrates the issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

  char w;

  int size = snprintf(&w, 1, "%s", "hello world");
  if(size<0) {
    abort();
  }

  char *buffer = malloc(size+1);
  snprintf(buffer, size+1, "%s", "hello world");

  printf("Wrote %d characters: %s\n", size, buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled like this:

```
$ gcc -Wformat-truncation=1 test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:8:31: warning: ‘%s’ directive output truncated writing 11 bytes into a region of size 1 [-Wformat-truncation=]
   int size = snprintf(&w, 1, "%s", "hello world");
                               ^~   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.c:8:7: note: ‘snprintf’ output 12 bytes into a destination of size 1
   int size = snprintf(&w, 1, "%s", "hello world");
```

Am I misinterpreting the documentation? I can't see how I could check the return value more than I am doing already.

Reference: [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534284/how-to-circumvent-format-truncation-warning-in-gcc) that implies the warning should not be raised. I really don't like disabling warnings and usually compile with `-Wall -Werror` so I'd appreciate some guidance here.

Comment: Why a downvote?

Comment: No idea why gcc acts like this. But shadowing the numerical size with a variable shuts it up. [godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/syPMM0).

Comment: @merlyn unfortunately `-O` then brings the warning back.

Comment: The first `snprintf` call will be unable to do more than write a null byte into `w`; that is warning-worthy.  What happens if you have `char w[2];` and modify the call appropriately?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The warning persists with `char w[2]` except of course it's now `...into a destination of size 2`

Comment: I see this behaviour on msys gcc 7.4, but not mingw gcc 8.3. I even tried adding in ` size >= 1` to see if that would satisfy it.