# warning: ‘/name0’ directive output may be truncated writing 10 bytes into a region of size between 1 and 4096 [-Wformat-truncation=]

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning, gcc8

```
#DEFINE LENGTH 4096

warning: ‘/name0’ directive output may be truncated writing 10 bytes into a region 
of size between 1 and 4096 [-Wformat-truncation=]
 snprintf(head_list->cname, LENGTH, "%s/name0", cpath);
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~
```

gcc is throwing this warning. How to fix this without using `-Wformat-truncation=` option?

`cpath` is a character with 4096 size

Comment: What is `head_list->cname`?

Comment: And if `head_list->cname` is a `char[10]`, then there is not enough space in the destination, hence `gcc` warns you about it.

Comment: Increate `LENGTH` so that `cpath` concatenated with `/name0` fits n `head_list->cname`

Comment: it is a pointer to a structure (struct details *head_list) and cname is a character member

Comment: head_list->cname is a char[LENGTH] and LENGTH is 4096 bytes

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534284/how-to-circumvent-format-truncation-warning-in-gcc answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

As `cpath` can be maximum 4096 characters long, appending `/name0` to the end of it inherently create a string that can be longer than 4096 characters and can't fit into `head_list->cname`

If you're sure that `cpath` can't be longer than 4090 characters then tell gcc to [turn off warning for that specific line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3378560/995714)

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wformat-truncation"
snprintf(head_list->cname, LENGTH, "%s/name0", cpath);
assert(strlen(cpath) <= 4090);
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```